# what is Future<void>?

Tags: java, vert.x

I have following code snippet.

```
import io.vertx.core.Future;
public void start(Future<void> fut){

  /*
  some code
  */
  fut.complete()
}
```

Why does **Future** used here?

Comment: `fut` could contain a `Callable<void>` object for example. Which you would want to call as it executes some logic but does not return anything. Therefore `<void>`

Comment: why complete() method is called at the end of the program?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Future<Void>` is a future result of an execution that returns no value.

That would be typically the result of invoking the `run` method of a `Runnable`.

The normal void call looks like (see `r.run()`):

```
Runnable r = () -> System.out.println("running");
r.run();
```

When such a call is done asynchronously, such as via an executor service or a completable future, it turns into a future:

```
Future<Void> future = CompletableService.runAsync(r);
```

It's just a future of an execution that returns no result. This "future" contains information about the execution, even though it has no "return" value (such as what `Future<Object>` would have).

You can get information about the asynchronous execution. Some examples of information it hods:

```
boolean finished = future.isDone(); //Check if the async execution has completed
future.get(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //Wait for completion with timeout
future.cancel(true); //cancel the execution
```

`java.lang.Void` is a reference type for `void` (a placeholder that doesn't get instantiated). So you can look at `Future<Void>` the same way you look at `Future<Object>`, just keeping in mind what you know about `void` not returning any value.

You can read more about these types here:

- [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/Future.html)
- [Void](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html)
- [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

Comment: Thanks. So, the complete() method is just to complete the execution, isn't it?

Comment: @Satish_Mhetre Yes. The code that implements the asyncronous behavior (the one that created the `Future` instance) is the one that calls `future.complete` to signal the end of the execution. If you have the JDK sources, take a look at, for example `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool`. There are `.complete()` calls after the async job is completed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it.